# iterate with v-for and data-attribute

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, v-for

I have a vuejs-datatable, and now I want to have an option-column with edit- / delete-links.

This is the table-body which gets iterated from the function `getRows()`:

```html
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(row, idr) in get_rows()" v-bind:key="idr">
    <td>{{row.id}}</td>
    <td>{{row.email}}</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="tblLink text-warning" :data-id="row.id" @click="userEdit"><b-icon-pencil-square></b-icon-pencil-square></a>
      <a href="#" class="tblLink text-danger" :data-id="row.id" @click="userDelete"><b-icon-trash></b-icon-trash></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now the `td` with the `{{row.id}}` and `{{row.email}}` are fine. However the `:data-id="row.id"` displays only the `id` of the first entry. Links in every row in my table have the same `data-id`. I do not understand why this is happening and what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Instead of using data-id, just pass row.id to userEdit(row.id) and userDelete(row.id).

Comment: It is a little bit unrelated but you should use computed properties instead of methods when using it as a representation of your data. So I would recommend change get_rows to computed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code below (notice, it's not using data-id):

```html
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(row, idr) in get_rows()" v-bind:key="idr">
    <td>{{row.id}}</td>
    <td>{{row.email}}</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="tblLink text-warning" @click="userEdit(row.id)"><b-icon-pencil-square></b-icon-pencil-square></a>
      <a href="#" class="tblLink text-danger" @click="userDelete(row.id)"><b-icon-trash></b-icon-trash></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Could you reference documentation or tutorial explaining why he can't use `data-id`?